# Authenticated file upload from Android App to Django Backend

Tags: android, django, authentication, file-upload

I would like to allow users to upload files from an Android App to a Django website. To prevent random uploads I want to limit this feature to authenticated users. For example by assigning the user a unique API key that could be sent in the request. Ideally the server should reject the requests as soon as possible to reduce the load. Otherwise I could simply send an extra parameter in the POST request but this would mean everything is uploaded before it can be accepted or rejected.

I would like to make this as simple as possible for authorized users and therefore avoid username/password session-management. A single random API key that I generate would be perfect.

Any pointers on what direction I should be looking into?

Answer (score 0):

If you include the authentication information in a header, you can reject unauthorized POSTs before you start reading the request body. You probably just want to use [HTTP Basic Auth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication); it's simple and standard. The Authorization header is meant for username/password, but you can easily express an API key or similar kind of credential in these terms.